# Upgrade database by using onUpgrade callback properly

Tags: database, flutter, dart, callback, sqflite

I'm fetching data from a website (JSON) and save it in a database. This works well. However, I want to upgrade the database with a new version number every time the data fetched from the internet changes. For that, I think the best way is to drop the table, upgrade the database number version and recreate the table before filling it with the new data (at least there is a way to insert only new records and update only the old ones that have changed).

I saw that it could be done with the `onUpgrade` callback on a Database from the [sqflite](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite) plugin.

So, I created an `Helper` with an `init()` method that open the database. 
However, I don't understand when the `onUpgrade` callback is called. Indeed, in this code below, `version` is always at 1.

I would like to have a method that init the DB and :

- creates it if it does not exists OR
- open the current version if no number version is specified (something like that) OR
- upgrade to a new version by auto-incrementing the version number (by calling database.upgrade() for example).

Do you think this is possible in a unique method or do I need to split that in two methods ? If yes, what's the point of the `onUpgrade` callback ?

```
class DBHelper {
  // Private constructor
  DBHelper._privateConstructor();

  // Get an instance of DBHelper
  static final DBHelper _dbHelper = DBHelper._privateConstructor();

  // Getter to get the instance of the DBHelper
  factory DBHelper() => _dbHelper;

  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await init();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> init() async {
    print("DBHelper: init database");
    // Get a location using path_provider
    String path = await getDBPath();
    // I THINK ALL HAPPENS HERE
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    print("DBHelper: _onCreate called");
    // When creating the db, create the table
    _createTable();
  }

  void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async{
    print("DBHelper: _onUpgrade called");
    try {
      await db.transaction((Transaction txn) async {
        await txn.execute("DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error : " + e.toString());
    }
    _createTable();
  }

  void _createTable() async {
    Database db = await database;
    try {
      await db.transaction((Transaction txn) async {
        await txn.execute("CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ("
            "TABLE_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            "TABLE_INT INTEGER,"
            "TABLE_TEXT TEXT,");");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error : " + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

Database versioning in sqflite matches what has been done in Android where the version is a constant for a particular version of your app with a particular schema. `onCreate/onUpgrade` should typically get called only once in the lifecyle of your application. Anyway it won't get called unless you close and re-open your database. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/migration_example.md.

So I would say that the user version as it exists now does not match your need. So I would not used this value nor `onUpgrade` in your scenario. However you could defined your own singleton value (i.e. your own versioning system) and drop/create table in a transaction while the database is open. Nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finally drop the idea of using this and create my own upgrade method that only drop the table and recreate it before filling it with new values.

Comment: Is there a way to update a database from a json and update only the rows where values have changed and add news records only ? It would be best for performance if I don't have to clear and refill the entire table. At least clearing table and rewrite rows is faster than run though each element of each row and check if it changed.

Comment: There is no easy mechanism for that in SQLite. Reading all the records and checking (in memory) which record has changed before updating/creating all the changed/new records in a transaction should actually be faster but more painful. Read is superfast, write is slower

Comment: Thanks for the infos ;) I'll stay with my option for now as it works well :)